# Do syscall read and write apply to System V message queue to send and receive messages

Tags: c, linux

As for System V message `int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg);`,

1. Can syscall `read` work like `msgsnd` to send a message?
2. Can syscall `write` work like `msgrcv`to receive a message?

Comment: Don't you have them backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they can't. The message queue identifier (returned by [`msgget`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html)) is not a descriptor.

Different sub-systems, different identifiers.